# Scratching my head over the root cause of Windows crashing

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash

I have a 2nd Windows 10 PC I'm using for a Docker server, and it frequently but randomly crashes into a full auto-reboot.

The Event Viewer lists all of these right around the time of the crash/reboot; the order here is just the way I happened to copy them:

---

```
Reported by component: Processor Core
Error Source: Machine Check Exception
Error Type: Cache Hierarchy Error
Processor APIC ID: 9
SCEP Certificate enrollment initialization for DOMAIN\USER$ via https://AMD-KeyId-578c545f796951421221a4a578acdb5f682f89c8.microsoftaik.azure.net/templates/Aik/scep failed:
GetCACaps
GetCACaps: Not Found
{"Message":"The authority \"amd-keyid-578c545f796951421221a4a578acdb5f682f89c8.microsoftaik.azure.net\" does not exist."}
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 06 Jan 2024 06:58:26 GMT
Content-Length: 121
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
x-ms-request-id: e3535bf7-eb0d-4a53-8022-0837347b1aaf

Method: GET(172ms)
Stage: GetCACaps
Not found (404). 0x80190194 (-2145844844 HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_FOUND)
```

> `The previous session did not finalize the tracking file on device \Device\HarddiskVolume3. The tracking file has been reset.`

> `The previous session did not finalize the tracking file on device \Device\HarddiskVolume8 (F:). The tracking file has been reset.`

> `The previous session did not finalize the tracking file on device \Device\HarddiskVolume5 (E:). The tracking file has been reset.`

> `The previous session did not finalize the tracking file on device \Device\HarddiskVolume6 (G:). The tracking file has been reset.`

> `The previous session did not finalize the tracking file on device \Device\HarddiskVolume7 (D:). The tracking file has been reset.`

> `The previous session did not finalize the tracking file on device \Device\HarddiskVolume1 (C:). The tracking file has been reset.`

> `A timeout was reached (45000 milliseconds) while waiting for the NvStreamNetworkSvc service to connect.`

```
Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
 Network link is disconnected.
```

> `A connection to the Windows Update service could not be established.`

> `The Network List Manager reports no connectivity to the internet.`

---

I've confirmed all firmware, BIOS, drivers and updates are fully updated. I also have a kick-arse cooler running on it that I've monitored, and overheating doesn't appear to be the cause. SMART Attributes for all drives show as "Good".

---

Specs:

[image]

Anyone have any idea what the root cause could be?